# Trying to make an Asyn ajax call and parse the response in JSON object

Tags: ajax, json, asynchronous

Firstly thanks for taking the time to read this, and I would like to  state I am new to this so forgive me if this seems too naive

Here is my problem ,I am making an AJAX call  and than trying to store the response in JSON format ,it works when I set Asyn parameter of the AJAX call as false, here is the code:

```
var ajax;
        var data;
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open('GET', 'https://api.soundcloud.com/users/'+userID+'/tracks.json?client_id='+clientID, false);
        ajax.send();
        data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
```

But when I set it to an asynchronous i.e replacing the false parameter by true call it gives me an error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

I have basic understanding of asyn calls , I conclude that the next data is fully fetched when the line `JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);` is executed.

Having said that is there some way I can still make the asynchronous call,and parse the data

Comment: What does the ResponseText look like?   What are the values of userID and clientID?  It sounds like you are getting an empty string back.

Comment: no I get a json string, from sound cloud api, I am kinda trying to implement a call back function for the parsing code but no success

Comment: What does the ResponseText look like? What are the values of userID and clientID?